# Why all Xorg log messages are written to journal at level 4 (warning)?

Tags: x11, xorg, logs, systemd-journald, gdm

All the content of `Xorg.n.log` can be viewed with `journalctl`. As `Xorg` is launched by `GDM` (if I understand it correctly), it always has the `--identifier=/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session`. But despite this hint given at the beginning of `Xorg.n.log`:

```
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3193]: Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3193]:         (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3193]:         (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
```

all the messages are at loglevel 4 (warning). This leads to tons of lines with `(**)`, `(==)`, `(II)` being erroneously marked as warnings, which makes it easy to miss actual warnings. Even more importantly, `(EE)` messages have loglevel 4 too, which seems critically wrong to me.

One possible semi-solution is to regex-filter out informational messages from `Xorg` completely, ([possible since `journald v253-rc1`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/24058)).
Another one is to use some complex piping-grepping to examine `journalctl` output (if anyone knows how to implement this, please explain, I'm a noob at this).
But *The Way* is of course to write `Xorg` messages at their proper loglevels in the first place, and I am completely lost here. How does `Xorg.n.log` content end up in the journal? Is it `GDM`'s, or `Xorg`'s, or `journald`'s work? Which of them decides on the loglevel of imported messages? And is it possible to hijack the process without rewriting and recompiling everything? And of course, should I submit an issue regarding this, and to which one of the projects? Thank you.

Version info:
Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64, 6.2.6-76060206-generic, GNOME 42.5, X.Org X Server 1.21.1.4, systemd 249 (249.11-0ubuntu3.7pop1~1681329414~22.04~2e1d714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"X is currently one of the last mainstream daemon which does not provide a way to log to the syslog" ... "fwiw, GDM now starts the X server to log exclusively to stdout and GDM then forwards this to the systemd journal".

-- [Bug 35473 - Ability to log to syslog](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35473)

I expect gdm-x-session is what decided to use "warning" as a default, as opposed to "info".

> And is it possible to hijack the process without rewriting and recompiling everything?

I don't think so!

I think it would be sufficient to get it to use syslog - it doesn't need to be journal-specific - but it would take work.

One challenge is the X server is designed to e.g. log its own segfaults.  So it is supposed to be able to work (for certain values of "work") from a signal handler.

```
/* This function does the actual log message writes. It must be signal safe.
 * When attempting to call non-signal-safe functions, guard them with a check
 * of the inSignalContext global variable. */
static void
LogSWrite(int verb, const char *buf, size_t len, Bool end_line)
```

Instead, I would suggest having gdm-x-session parse the X loglevel markers.  This would be similar to what systemd does with loglevel prefixes -

> SyslogLevelPrefix=
>
> Takes a boolean argument. If true and StandardOutput= or
> StandardError= are set to journal or kmsg (or to the same settings
> in combination with +console), log lines written by the executed
> process that are prefixed with a log level will be processed with
> this log level set but the prefix removed. If set to false, the
> interpretation of these prefixes is disabled and the logged lines
> are passed on as-is. This only applies to log messages written to
> stdout or stderr. For details about this prefixing see [sd-daemon(3)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-daemon.html). Defaults to true.

It's probably not as important for whatever starts XWayland, because XWayland does not emit any logs when it is happy.  For example, it seems to not log the explanation about "Markers:" during startup.  So if all the XWayland messages are being marked as warnings, that's not a big problem.

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite understand. How is syslog related to all these things? Isn't it something from pre-journald era?

Comment: The syslog() functions are portable across POSIX compatible systems. `systemd` supports them with or without a third-party syslog daemon.